# How to append arrays in Excel for Covariance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with the `covariance` formula in excel which takes in data in the form of two arrays.

> Example: Covariance of array A and array B would equal covariance.P(array A, array B).

My problem is that I am working with multiple arrays for each set of data.

How do I calculate covariance between two sets each consisting of multiple arrays?

> Example:  Covariance of A U B U C and D U E U F =covariance(?????).

I tried using `covariance(A+B+C, D+E+F)` but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Covariance or [COVARIANCE.P function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/COVARIANCEP-function-6f0e1e6d-956d-4e4b-9943-cfef0bf9edfc) or [COVARIANCE.S function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/COVARIANCES-function-0a539b74-7371-42aa-a18f-1f5320314977) or [COVAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COVAR-function-50479552-2C03-4DAF-BD71-A5AB88B2DB03)? Are you trying to use full column references as the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some simple trick that I am not figuring out that would allow `COVARIANCE.P` to work the way you want it to.  But the other option is to just perform the calculation manually since it really is not "that" bad.  To understand the calculation just check out [Wikipedia Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance):

> [image]

Basically that means the average of the products `E[XY]` minus the product of the averages `E[X]*E[Y]`.

So assuming {`A` `B` `C`} {`D` `E` `F`} are actually valid ranges you can use this array formula to calculate the covariance:

```
=AVERAGE(A*D,B*E,C*F)-(AVERAGE(A,B,C)*AVERAGE(D,E,F))
```

*Note: Array formulas are entered with:* <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Now, adding more criteria would change it as such:

- {`A` `B` `C` `D`} {`E` `F` `G` `H`}

  ```
  =AVERAGE(A*E,B*F,C*G,D*H)-(AVERAGE(A,B,C,D)*AVERAGE(E,F,G,H))
  ```
- {`A` `B` `C` `D` `E`} {`F` `G` `H` `I` `J`}

  ```
  =AVERAGE(A*F,B*G,C*H,D*I,E*J)-(AVERAGE(A,B,C,D,E)*AVERAGE(F,G,H,I,J))
  ```
- {`A` `B` `C` `D` `E` `F`} {`G` `H` `I` `J` `K` `L`}

  ```
  =AVERAGE(A*G,B*H,C*I,D*J,E*K,F*L)-(AVERAGE(A,B,C,D,E,F)*AVERAGE(G,H,I,J,K,L))
  ```